# Is using the google appengine parent attribute to apply default permissions to an object a good idea?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, authorization

While hacking together an authorization framework for my web app, I thought a lot of my work would be cut out if by default I applied the following logic. All objects created by a 'User' have a parent being the 'User'. When a query is run to retrieve objects for a view, limit the returned objects by applying the ancestor() property to the Query. This seems in my head simple and sensible would work in all the cases I can think of. No one else seems to have done it though, am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you aim is to cordon-off all the objects that are related to a single account, then you might want to look at the [multi-tenancy](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/multitenancy/overview.html) features, which are designed to do just this.

If your aim is just to have a convienent way to grab everything created by a single user, then we would need to know more about what your app does.

By setting the User as the parent for everything created by that user, you are placing everything related to that user into a single [Entity Group](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities.html#Entity_Groups_and_Ancestor_Paths), which means that if users in your application frequently need to update each other's data your might run into issues.

Comment: thanks - the user of an application will be able to create a range of other objects including other users. The idea came to me when trying to work out how to retrieve all the objects a user should be able to modify - the ancestor seemed to be a natural way to do it even though they are intended for transactions

Comment: I think what your looking for is a Kindless Query like `db.Query().filter("owner =", user)` which (assuming all your entities have owner set to your user) will return all the kinds of entities

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

This would place all of the user's data in the same entity group, which forces it all to reside on the same datastore node. If you need to update a user's data frequently, storing everything in one entity group is going to increase write contention and generally degrade performance.

The recommended design pattern is to [place 2 entities in the same group when they need to be updated in the same transaction](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities.html#Entity_Groups_and_Ancestor_Paths). Otherwise, don't use them.